# Calculate the number of instructions replaced ?

Tags: computer-architecture

I was studying a cs book for computer architecture(computer organization and design) and I found this exercise:

`Program A runs on a processor with clock rate 1GHz in 10s. To improve the performance of the program we substitute each instruction(X*4) with 2 add instructions(X + X and then X + X). The CPI of multiplication is 4 and for the addition is 1. The new program runs in 9s. How many multiplication instructions have been substituted?`

To solve this I used the MIPS equation:

```
I named the program with additions B, so :
MIPS(A) = (Clock Rate * 10^9 Hz) / (CPI * 10^6) = 250

For B:
MIPS(B) = .... = 1000

Then I used the other MIPS equation: MIPS = Instruction count / (Execution time * 10^6)
So solving both for Instruction count my final two formulas yield:
Instruction Count(A) = ..... = 25 * 10^8
Instruction Count(B) = ..... = 90 * 10^8

Therefore,there were added 65 * 10^8 instructions.
```

Because there are no solutions for the book I would like to know if I am correct or not. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/).

Comment: This (quite useless, imh) exercise problem asks you to do basic arithmetics. Do you have any question about the *concepts*? We don't do homework grading here.

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong approach, because you are assuming that each program does **nothing but** add or **nothing but** multiply.

I don't know what "the MIPS equations" are but I recommend that you try first principles rather than looking for official-sounding equations.

Each replacement of $X*4$ with $X+X,\,X+X$ saves $2$ clock cycles.

The replacement has reduced the run time by one second, which is $10^9$ clock cycles.

Simple division will tell you how many replacements have been made.

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/questions-about-correctness-of-a-solution).